# How to start an activity from a specific view?

Tags: android, view, xtify

I am developing an application for Android with the following visual scheme: 
[image: Visual scheme of my Android app]

One of the buttons is the option of visualizing all the notifications obtained via Xtify. For doing this, [Xtify's site](http://developer.xtify.com/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=3539052) suggests the following invocation:

```
public void displayRNInbox(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RichNotifInboxActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

However, this opens up a completely new window, therefore losing sight of the upper bar of my desired scheme. Is it possible for this new window to only occupy the space defined by the framelayout?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: its not possible for an activity. u will need a fragment in this situation

Comment: @HirakChhatbar could you provide a bit more detail? I am relatively new to Android programming so I don't understand much. I looked into [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), is it necessary to create a new class which extends Fragments?

Comment: @Soph you have to manage both layout, then show/hide on button click, this is complex way.
Else just change activity setcontentview, on click listener.

Comment: a beginner with over 1k reputation :o. anyways, to start with fragments, here is a link for good tutorials.... give some time to this and u will master this stuff... fragments are the most important introduction in the android i guess, because they can be added, replaced or removed dynamically, whenever we want, wherever we want

Comment: @HirakChhatbar Well I had dropped all programming-related activities for a while, so Android is a complete new world to me. :) Could you pass the link? Didn't get it. Thanks!

Comment: aah... ohkay.. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo